# Problems with scanf and struct

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read two variables inside a struct but I'm facing some problems using scanf. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct {
    int pc;
    char* label;
} sb;
```

... and here is the instantiation of the struct:

```
sb input;
fscanf (in, "%s%d", input.label, &(input.pc));
printf ("%s %d\n", input.label, input.pc);
```

I was expecting as output a 'c-string' and an integer but for some reason it gave me: (null) and -971303966.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you have not actually allocated any storage in the structure for the label.  One solution is to change the declaration to:

```
typedef struct {
    int pc;
    char label[80];
} sb;
```

But please be aware that code is now dangerous because it reads into the buffer without putting any limits on the read so it can overflow the buffer.

Comment: "scanf using %s will take the entire line" is not so.  `"%s"` will cause `fscanf()` to scan in non-white-space which does not, at least, include the line's `'\n'`.

Comment: Thanks - forgot the semantics of %s - now I remember why I don't use it.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

"Label" in your struct is just a pointer, nothing that can hold a string. You have to either allocate some memory for it

```
Input.label = (char*)malloc(122);
```

Or change your struct to

```
typedef struct { int pc; char label[122]; } sb;
```

Be carefull about the amount of memory you allocate for the string. Preferably use fscanf_s, so you can declare the maximum length to read.

Comment: Ok, that works. But if I take those two variables outside the struct, the code works. http://pastebin.com/d8q0bvAE

Comment: You were just lucky then - it could also have crashed.  It will depend on what value the uninitialized variable label happens to contain.

Comment: This question is tagged [c], not [c++], so you need to use `malloc` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf(in, "%s%d", input.label, &(input.pc))` results in undefined behavior (UB) because there is no memory associated with `input.label` in which `fscanf()` attempts to save.

1) Avoid using `fscanf()`. Recommend `fgets()/sscanf()`
2) Check the return value from any `scanf()` like function.
3) Allocate space for `label`

```
void Read_sb(sb *data) {
  sb->pc = 0;
  sb->label = NULL;

  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_IOErrroOrEOF();

  char s[sizeof buf];
  if (sscanf(buf, "%s%d", s, &sb->pc) != 2) Handle_FormatError();
  sb->label = strdup(s);
}
```